# "Ctrl + click to follow link" in VSCode terminal does not jump to source file but opens new browser tab

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I'm using **Visual Studio Code** (version 1.40.1) to work on my **Angular 8** project and run **Karma/Jasmine** tests from its terminal through the command `ng test`. When a test failed, I was always able to jump to the related source file through `Ctrl + click` on a terminal link, embedded in a stack-trace. Since a few days, this doesn't work anymore but a new Chrome browser tab is opened instead.

[image]

I thought the problem could be related to any recent updated `npm` package. Therefore I created a brand-new Angular 8 project (`ng new`), made a small change in `app.component.spec.ts` and started `ng test`. Unfortunately the same problem appears there as well. Completely uninstalling and reinstalling VSCode didn't help either.

Any idea on how I can get the original functionality (jump to source) back?

***package.json***

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.13",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.13",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.13",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.13",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.13",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.18",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.18",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.13",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.13",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

***karma.config.js***

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/app'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true
  });
};
```

Comment: for that url in exception it will take you to browser only, if it was some compilation issue, it will take you to file. depends on location its showing in error.

Comment: @Aakash Garg: I'm sure, it worked in the past. I was able to jump to the related line in the source file when an error occurred in the test.

Comment: try my solution below.

Comment: Does that help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61819887/webpack-directory-appended-at-error-after-migrating-to-angular9

Comment: @David: Thanks for your comment! I followed the instructions from https://stackoverflow.com/q/61819887/2358409 as you suggested and now, it works again. I however don't exactly understand why this solved my problem. Can you maybe post an awardable answer with some further explanations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Ctrl + click does not navigate to the file directly because the error stack displays `http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/src/app/app.component.spec.ts` instead of `src/app/app.component.spec.ts`.

You can use the option suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62122024/1160794), which consists in specifying a `formatError` function in `karma.conf.js` config

```
 formatError: (msg) =>
  msg.replace(/http:\/\/localhost:9876\/_karma_webpack_\//g, '')
```

This will cause karma to use the method above (which completely removes `http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_` from the stack trace) when formatting the error stack.

Now, as to why this happens, I'm not sure. I check an old angular 7 project, with old dependencies for karma /jasmine/... it worked as before (i.e. the error stack refered directly to file in `src`).

I then upgraded karma, jasmine, karma-jasmine,... to the latest version and it still worked.

I started having the same problem when I upgraded to angular 8. So something must have changed somewhere, but I don't know where

Answer (score 1):

For my case, had to add angularCompilerOptions.strictTemplates to tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting crazy, it stopped working from one day to another. Researching, I realized that VS had applied an automatic update, and disabled some Angular extensions, I do not know why? (In my case, it happened developing an angular 8 application).

So the working solution for me was going to extensions, filter by "@disabled" and enable the angular -or whatever in your case- extension

Comment: Unfortunately your proposal doesn't work for me, I found no `disabled` extension in my VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

Open VsCode, press F1, Search open user settings, click on open user settings. a window will come. search terminal on left and try turning off allowchords to false.

[image]

If instead of this window you see a json. Put :-

```
"terminal.integrated.allowChords": false
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your tsconfig.json:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictTemplates": true
 }
```

Worked for me, hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is unreal, found the solution:
If the terminal is small, it will open in editor, if big in browser, so try just enlarging the terminal if you keep it on the right  or left side like I do....
[Bigger no problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/889bf.png)

[Smaller problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4VQa.png)