# Webpack directory appended at error after migrating to Angular9

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, jasmine2.0, karma-webpack

I've recently upgraded my projet from angular 7 to angular 9.

When I run the tests (`ng test`), I always get `http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/` appendend to the error, hence in visual studio code, we can't click on the error to got directly to the file.

For the sake of testing, I've added `expect(2).toEqual(1);` in the `app.component.spec.ts` file

For example, with the angular 7 projet out of the box, I get this error with ng test:

```
Chrome 81.0.4044 (Windows 10.0.0) AppComponent should have as title 'angular7app' FAILED
        Expected 2 to equal 1.
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (src/app/app.component.spec.ts:23:12)
```

as for the angular 9, I get this error:

```
Chrome 81.0.4044.122 (Windows 10) AppComponent should have as title 'untaire' FAILED
        Error: Expected 2 to be 1.
            at <Jasmine>
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/src/app/app.component.spec.ts:23:12)
```

When I check the versions in the package.json, theses are the changes that affects Karma and jasmine:

```
"@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8"                    to "~3.5.0"
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3"                 to "~2.0.3" (no changes)
"jasmine-core": "~2.99.1"                     to "~3.5.0"
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",            to "~4.2.1" (no changes)
"karma": "~4.0.0",                            to "~5.0.0"
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",            to "~3.1.0"
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1", to "~2.1.0"
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",                    to "~3.0.1"
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",      to "^1.4.2"
```

I've checked and I didn't found anything about this new behavior on any of theses packages

Answer (score 5):

You can add to `karma.conf.js` configuration property `formatError`:

```
formatError: (msg) =>
  msg.replace(/http:\/\/localhost:9876\/_karma_webpack_\//g, '')
```

But not sure that is the best practice, however I cannot search alternative change format output location error in documentation karma http://karma-runner.github.io/4.0/config/configuration-file.html

Comment: Thanks. This is exacly what I was searching for.